# changing a forms action attribute dynamically in a go template

Tags: go, go-templates

Currently the forms action attribute is hardcoded to the id=2

How would I dynamically set it to the ID chosen by the user when pressing submit.

[image]

```
<p>Select a group</p>

      <form method="POST" action="/artists/id?id=2">
      <label for="selection">Artists:</label>
      <select id="selection" name="selection">
            
            <option value=1>Queen</option>
            
            <option value=2>Pink Floyd</option>
            
            <option value=3>Scorpions</option>
            
         
            
      </select>
      <input type = "submit" value ="submit" />
      </form>
```

Go template:

```
<p>Select a group</p>
      <form method="POST" action="/artists/id?id=2">
      <label for="selection">Artists:</label>
      <select id="selection" name="selection">
            {{range .}}
            <option value={{.Id}}>{{.Name}}</option>
            {{end}}
      </select>
      <input type = "submit" value ="submit" />
      </form>
```

Comment: Remove query string from action.  Change id of select to "id".   Add "selected" attribute to the default option (presumably the one with value = 2).

Comment: Either use Javascript in the template to change it when selection changes, or, if you can, change the API to accept the `id` in request body instead of a query param, and simply submit the form and get the value of `selection`

Answer (score 1):

Used form method="GET" and made the changes suggested by @cerise